# How to test weird `font-size` definition in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-size

I recently came across this odd definition of `font-size:` in css, and I flagged it as a bug during a code review.

The way browsers deal with "relative" font sizes through `rem` is very clear to me, but I've never come across a font size definition as below:

```
.xx-small {
    font-size: xx-small;
}

.x-small {
    font-size: x-small;
}

.small {
    font-size: small;
}

.medium {
    font-size: medium;
}

.large {
    font-size: large;
}

.x-large {
    font-size: x-large;
}

.xx-large {
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

And apparently is W3C standard compliant (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)

**The questions:**

1. **Is this a reliable way to define the font size across browsers?**
2. **What is it based upon? Is it relative to some default value?**
3. **Is there a way to test these font size definitions work nicely across different browsers and devices?**

Comment: What is the question? I mean, I could answer _"give something a style of `font-size: x-large` and see if it works"_ but I've got a feeling that would be too easy. Is there more to it? Maybe my question should be, why do you think these keywords are weird?

Comment: Alright, I've updated the questions at the bottom :)

Comment: That makes the question clearer, yes, but I must emphasise that these keywords are not weird just because you've never heard of them! They have been around since the very first draft of the CSS standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this a reliable way to define the font size across browsers?

No, since the sizes are based on the browsers' default font sizes (that can be set by the users in the preferences), so they differ between systems.
So you can use these if you want to respect the users' preferences. If you just want to set the same font size in all browsers, use pixels.

> 2. What is it based upon? Is it relative to some default value?

Yes, `medium` is the default font size. Note that this is the same as `1rem`, but only   if you do  NOT set a font size for the `html` element in your stylesheet.

> 3. Is there a way to test these font size definitions work nicely across different browsers and devices?

Well, they do work nicely on all browsers, since this has been around since forever (CSS1, and even before that, in the `<font>` element), but the defaults may differ, and the relative font sizes may differ between browsers and between quirks/standards mode.

Conclusion: these are not suitable for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it opened up my mind :D 
Especially the answer to the first question `these are based on the browsers' default font sizes`. It actually makes sense now.